# Javascript: How to set style selector from var

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem with styles in JavaScript.

I have a object like: **styles = {background:'blue',width:'1000px'}**

I need write function which takes every attributes from **styles** object and apply it as a CSS selectors of some HTML element.

something like:

```
function stylize(def){
     for(var key in def){
         document.getElementById("test").style.***SELECTOR***=def[key];
     }
```

}

but how get style selector by value of **key** value?

I need pure JS solution withour jquery etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the square bracket notation:

```
function stylize(def) {
    for (var key in def) {
        document.getElementById("test").style[key] = def[key];
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: this is just an example; not production code.</sup>

Comment: This is the right solution, but gosh, let's extract the `getElementById` from inside the loop, or preferably just make the element another parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is:

```js
function setStylesByObj(el, styleObj) {
    var css = [];
    for (var prop in styleObj) {
        if (styleObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            css.push(prop + ': ' + styleObj[prop]);
        }
    }

    el.style.cssText = css.join(';');
}

var styles = {
    background: 'blue',
    height: '10em',
    width: '1000px'
};

setStylesByObj(document.getElementById('demo'), styles);
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="color: orange; font-weight: bold">Hello there, world.</div>
```

Though the above explicitly overwrites the existing `style` attribute; to preserve those attributes, it might be better to concatenate, rather than over-write:

```js
function setStylesByObj(el, styleObj) {
    var css = [];
    for (var prop in styleObj) {
        if (styleObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            css.push(prop + ': ' + styleObj[prop]);
        }
    }

    el.style.cssText += css.join(';');
}

var styles = {
    background: 'blue',
    height: '10em',
    width: '1000px'
};

setStylesByObj(document.getElementById('demo'), styles);
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="color: orange; font-weight: bold">Hello there, world.</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused why you would construct strings and join them and use `cssText` when you could just set each style directly on the `style` property of the element.

Comment: Hmm, agreed; this was presented after another answer already presented use of the `for...in` to set properties directly on the element. This is less a recommendation, more as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Underscore's `_.extend`, or its jQuery equivalent `$.extend`, or similar object assignment routine from your favorite library:

```
_.extend(element.style, styles);
```

This is essentially the same as @SalmanA's solution, just using a library routine if it's handy.

Answer (score -1):

you could replace any dash with a Capital letter, just like this:

```
document.getElementById("test").style['backgroundColor'] = "#ff0000";
```

in case you want a ready functionwhich dose the replacement, use jQuery libaray's jQuery.css:

```
jQuery("#test").css({'background-color':'#ff0000'})
```

Comment: But the OP explicitly excluded jQuery, besides the fact that this solution does not solve his problem.

Answer (score -1):

or you can do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?